# Gregorio - How to get 5 line staff

Tags: luatex, gregorio

wondering if there's a way to get a 5 line staff output with Gregorio. Default is 4 line staff, but I have read all the documentation and seems possible but they didn't mention how.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please help us help you and add a minimal working example (MWE) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Have you seen https://www.mail-archive.com/gregorio-users@gna.org/msg01977.html ? I don’t know whether the situation has changed since that thread was written.

Comment: Ah, yes, it has changed: https://www.mail-archive.com/gregorio-users@gna.org/msg03387.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add `staff-lines: 5;` to the header of your `gabc` file:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{score.gabc}
name: Some name;
mode: 1;
language: latin;
staff-lines: 5;

%%

(c4) V/. Ky(f)ri(d)e(d) e(d)le(d)i(c)son(d.) (::)

\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[autocompile]{gregoriotex}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[latin]{babel}

\begin{document}
\gregorioscore{score}
\end{document}
```

[image]