# Setting number of staff lines outside the header using snippet

Tags: gregorio

I would like to use the \gabcsnippet command inside my LaTeX. However, I need 5 lines, not 4.

Is there a way to modify the staff-lines header with a command like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{gregoriotex}

\begin{document}
    
    %\greCommandToSetStaffLinesTo{5} % what I'm looking for

    \gabcsnippet{
        staff-lines: 5; % this obviously doesn't work.
        (c3) Vi(hgh)
    }
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find out, whether or not your code would work (in hindsight, after writing this answer, it can't work, see [last bullet](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/support/gregoriotex)). However, the package seems to rely on external files, which follow the gabc-format.

This [solution from Marcel Krüger](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/440521/245790) shows how to create 5 staff lines. First he writes, what he needs, into a file called score.gabc (`\begin{filecontents*}{score.gabc}`), which he later includes via `\gregorioscore{score}`. Alternatively you could create `score.gabc` with a text editor yourself and leave out the `filecontents` part.

Just for convenience, not to earn laurels I don't deserve, here is a copy of his code:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}% <<< this part you could replace by a manual edit of score.gabc
\begin{filecontents*}{score.gabc}
name: Some name;
mode: 1;
language: latin;
staff-lines: 5;

%%

(c4) V/. Ky(f)ri(d)e(d) e(d)le(d)i(c)son(d.) (::)

\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass[12pt]{article}% <<< here the Latex-document begins

\usepackage[autocompile]{gregoriotex}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[latin]{babel}

\begin{document}
\gregorioscore{score}% <<< here's the include
\end{document}
```

Where to find out more?

- the [package documentation](https://ctan.org/pkg/gregoriotex) is a bit wild for a beginner to this package and this world of music
- however, it contains a link to [The Gregorio project](http://gregorio-project.github.io/index.html) with an abundance of details, howtos and explanations
- also following *sources* on the [package site](https://ctan.org/pkg/gregoriotex) mentions a nice [description of how this package works](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/support/gregoriotex), see also the [Wiki](https://gregoriochant.org/dokuwiki/doku.php):

> ... Gregorio's main job is to convert a gabc file (simple text
> representation of a score) into a GregorioTeX file, which ...

See also [limitations of \gabcsnippet](http://gregorio-project.github.io/tutorial/tutorial-snippet-01.html). At least there staff-lines doesn't seem to work, while other entries do.

[image: limitations]

Try also the [online editor (alpha)](https://www.sourceandsummit.com/editor/alpha/) for gabc-input.

[image: gabc online editor]

Comment: Thank you for the very informative post. All of this I already know – I am not new to LaTeX (only new to this forum) and have worked a lot with Gregorio's docs and webpages. In the link to \gabcsnippet tutorial there is mentioned a workaround for including one of the headers (mode) using \greannoation. I wondered if there is a similar workaround for staff-lines. In docs it is not mentioned explicitly that such a function is not supported (or at least I didn't find it). I was already considering {filecontents} solution, but \gabcsnippet would be better for my case – I only need those 5 lines...

Comment: Ok. // I didn't find info about \gabcsnippet there either. The only option would be to check the source code. E.g. \GreBeginScore#1#2#3#4#5#6#7#8 is mentioned on p. 91 in the manual. Once you know all the parameters to set, it promisses to set staff-lines, too. No idea, if it will cooperate with \gabcsnippet . There seems to be some issue with it. // Why can't you work with notes a-c and k-m on 4 lines? https://gregoriochant.org/dokuwiki/doku.php/cheat_sheet

Comment: I am making an edition of some music in modal notation, where the manuscript uses 5-staff line. I also checked the source code but it seems to not incorporate well with the \gabcsnippet. I didn't use \GeBeginScore though, only \GreHeader{staff-lines}{5}%, will give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution might be to use a minipage that includes a `gregorioscore` command added in the usual way. This would allow you to have a score that looks more like something produced with `gabcsnippet` but with five lines, since that comes from the header of the gabc file. This may cause some other problems, however.

Also, for what it's worth, `greannotation` used directly (right before a score, that is, each and every time, e.g. two calls would give something like "Ant. ad Magnificat" and "1. D" for a mode I antiphon with the D ending) or, better, in directly in another macro such as a `newcommand` — or `NewDocumentCommand` — that also incorporates the classic `gregorioscore` macro (even if it is simply calling the header information via yet another macro) is the better way to add information such as a modal indicator. To me, the control given the appearance by default (such as using only old-style numbers if this is loaded for the whole document via `fontspec` makes it worthwhile to allow a default inclusion of any information in the gabc file but to overwrite it as soon as you add `greannotation` to the tex file.

I know that doesn't solve the problem yet, but it might explain why an annotation is still usable with `gabcsnippet`; the next question then is whether five lines in the context of `gabcsnippet` is even a possibility for future inclusion in Gregorio (but it's worth asking imho).